# Can AWS API Gateway make a backend connection with a VPN?

Tags: amazon-web-services, vpn, aws-api-gateway

We need to create an API interface for a client, so as to avoid having the client connect directly to the vendor. The interface could serve mostly as a passthrough for the various API calls. The vendor requires a VPN connection, and I am not quite clear if this can be accomplished with AWS API Gateway, as my reading shows the backend must be publicly available.

We are in no way married to AWS, so if there is a simpler solution for this, I am all ears.

Comment: There are lot of things you can do... which is why I don't believe this response merits the status of an 'answer.' One that comes to mind though is hosting your own VPN gateway using Strongswan or the like on ec2 and then routing to a private subnet which hosts your API

Answer (score 3):

At the moment, you cannot directly connect to a VPN through API Gateway Proxy but you can place your Lambda's in a VPC and connect your VPN to the VPC where Lambda will be able to work as a proxy and connect to your backend.

Alternative option is to use client certificates at API Gateway to securely connect to your backends.

Comment: I would like to know why the answer was down voted? is there any improvement to be made? or the answer is not relevant or incorrect?